# Robotics: Want MicroC Pro PIC Sample Code?

Tags: pic, robotics, microc

I'm new to robotics.
I have to develop a line following robot. 
I hope to use PIC18F452 microchip.
I am looking for alredy developed source code to start with. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/diunuge/SLIIT--Robofest-2012) codebase is developed for a robot with line following and quite advanced other functionalities. This also includes some circuits, you may find useful.